# Trying to access some elements in an IndexSet

Tags: swift, nsindexset

I'm using `IndexSet` and I'm trying to access some indexes which at times are consecutive and at other times are not.

For example, my set may contain `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 13, 31]`

I want to pull out of the set a range of `3...13`, but am having difficulty with the syntax. I've learned how to use the function commands from Apple documentation, by using `myIndexSet.sorted()`. However, the Apple Documentation does not give an example of how to access a range of elements in the set. The Apple Documentation for accessing elements in the index set are the following:

```
subscript(Range<IndexSet.Index>)
```

I've tried a number of ways to write this but can't figure out how to do it right. Can someone show me how to access a range of elements in the set to create a new set? I've tried things such as:

```
let subset = subscript(Range: myLargerSet.3...13)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: `let slice = indexSet[indexSet.indexRange(in: 3...13)]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [intersection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexset/1780212-intersection) of your `IndexSet` (`[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 13, 31]`) with another `IndexSet` (`[3, 4, ..., 12, 13]`):

```
let yourIndexSet: IndexSet = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 13, 31]
let desiredIndexRange = IndexSet(3...13)
let indicesOfInterest = yourIndexSet.intersection(desiredIndexRange)
print(indicesOfInterest.sorted()) // => [3, 5, 6, 7, 13]
```

Comment: Thanks this worked and the following also gave me some helpful understanding.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use a filter to create a new `IndexSet`.

```
let set = IndexSet(arrayLiteral: 1,2,3,5,6,7,13,31)
let subset = set.filteredIndexSet { (index) -> Bool in
    index >= 3 && index <= 13
}
```

Comment: This is good because it doesn't require the allocation of a new index set (which can be large if the range is large), but I don't like the syntax, as you wrote it. I would suggest `3 <= index && index <= 13` instead, or better yet: `3...13 ~= index`.

Comment: Perhaps: `let set: IndexSet = [1,2,3,5,6,7,13,31]; let subset = set.filteredIndexSet{ 3...13 ~= $0 }`

Comment: Or if you're really crazy: `set.filteredIndexSet(includeInteger: (3...13).contains)`

Answer (score 0):

You can access a slice of your original set as follows:

```
let slice = indexSet[indexSet.indexRange(in: 3...13)]
```

`slice` accesses the existing elements in place, so creation of the slice is O(1)

Comment: `accesses the existing elements in place` does not imply `O(1)`. Or are you talking about space complexity?

Comment: Could you explain how `indexSet.indexRange(in: 3...13)` differs from `IndexSet(3...13)`? I don't quite understand the difference

Comment: @Alexander "A slice stores a base collection and the start and end indices of the view. It does not copy the elements from the collection into separate storage. Thus, creating a slice has O(1) complexity." - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bidirectionalslice

Comment: That would only be applicable for randomly addressable, contiguously stored elements. If `IndexSet` is implemented as a regular HashSet (A HashMap from elements to themselves), then they're stored non-contiguously, and such an operation would require a lookup of each element in-turn.

Comment: Just looked into the implementation of [`NSIndexSet` on Linux](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/9cb8ca1029650c0f3b3933210d61a6f3efe7f7b7/Foundation/NSIndexSet.swift)(which backs `IndexSet`), it stores the elements in memory as an `[Range<Int>]`. I don't think slicing that could really be done in `O(1)`